# Concat two dataframes with different indices

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am trying to concatenate two dataframes. I've tried using merge(), join(), concat() in pandas, but none gave me my desired output.

> df1:

| Index | value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 2 | c |
| 3 | d |
| 4 | e |

> df2:

| Index | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | f |
| 2 | g |
| 3 | h |
| 4 | i |
| 5 | j |

> desired output:

| Index | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | f |
| 1 | b | g |
| 2 | c | h |
| 3 | d | i |
| 4 | e | j |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you elaborate the rules to get to the result? what do you try to match between both dataframes?

Comment: You can remove the index (`reset_index(drop=True)`) and add a new index after merging (if the index if the resulting df is just supposed to be an index starting at zero and not the one of df1)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `pd.merge` and specify the index left join as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'value': list('ABCDE')})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'value': list('FGHIJ')}, index=range(1, 6))

pd.merge(df1.rename(columns={'value': 'col1'}), df2.reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns={'value': 'col2'}), how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)

-----------------------------------
    col1  col2
0   A     F
1   B     G
2   C     H
3   D     I
4   E     J
-----------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Does resetting the index of df2 work for your use case?

```
pd.concat([df1,df2.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1) \
    .set_axis(['Col1', 'Col2'], axis=1, inplace=False)
```

**Result**

```
  Col1 Col2
0    a    f
1    b    g
2    c    h
3    d    i
4    e    j
```